# Complex schema validation in Karate

Tags: java, karate

I'm trying to validate the response schema with karate but facing issue with array.
Attaching the response and feature as well as my schema.json.

Response -

```
{
"page": 1,
"per_page": 6,
"total": 12,
"total_pages": 2,
"data": [
    
    {
        "id": 3,
        "email": "emma.wong@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Emma",
        "last_name": "Wong",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/3-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Eve",
        "last_name": "Holt",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/4-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "email": "charles.morris@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Charles",
        "last_name": "Morris",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/5-image.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "email": "tracey.ramos@reqres.in",
        "first_name": "Tracey",
        "last_name": "Ramos",
        "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/6-image.jpg"
    }
],
"support": {
    "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
    "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
}
```

}

```
 Scenario: Get all Users and validate schema
    Given url getUrl
    When method Get
    Then status 200
    And print response
    Then match response == '#object'
    * string jsonSchemaExpected = read('file:src/test/resources/features/sample/responseSchema.json')
    And print response.data.length 
    And match response == jsonSchemaExpected
```

**responseSchema.json**

> {
> "page": "#number",
> "per_page": "#number",
> "total": "#number",
> "total_pages": "#number",
> "data": "#[] #object",
> "support": "#object"
> }

Comment: I'm going to pass on this question as I think it can be made simpler instead of just dumping your situation as-is. I suggest you search for other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only observation I have is if you cast to a string, you won't be able to do any matching.

Instead of `* string jsonSchemaExpected` do `* def jsonSchemaExpected`.

Comment: Thanks @peter it worked, i replaced the string with def.